# Javascript not re-fire when going from one ajax page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

JavaScript datetimepicker is not working when clicked next through the Ajax pages. The datetimepicker works on the first load of the first Ajax page but when next button is clicked it re-loads the same page but with different information and the picker doesn't work. ????

This is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#processform").keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which == 13) {
           var tagName = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase(); 
           if (tagName !== "textarea") {
               return false;
           }
       }
    });
    $( "#datepossible" ).datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss', separator: ' ' });
    $( "#datepossible" ).datetimepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
    $( "#datepossible" ).datetimepicker( "option", "showAnim", "blind" );
});
```

Comment: Is the first section is being removed or just being hided when other page is shown? Because if youre just hiding the first section, it's gonna result a duplicate id problem on `$( "#datepossible" )`.

Comment: You need to re-initiate the datepicker after the ajax content containing the datepicker input is loaded. When fireing the ajax request you can use a success callback to do that.

Comment: The page seems to be not completing the on complete event, therefore only re-loading the contents of the `<div>` not the page.